# pass browser profile name for a command which opens the default browser from terminal / shell

Tags: google-chrome, browser, zsh, azure-cli

I am trying to login to azure from cli using `az login` . As per azure documentation, it opens a new tab asking to login on the default browser if `edge browser` is not installed. However, I want to open a specific profile as I use different profiles for different user accounts.

Eg : if I use `az login`, it opens the default browser with default profile

if I use `azAd login` (assume I create `azAd` as an `alias` for `az with profile name for default browser`, it opens the default browser with the passed in profile name

Answer (score 0):

I some how managed to do it in a tricky way. If there is a better way I can find, I will update it. But for now, this is what I did

```
balogin() {
    # chrome profile names in the browser UI and their profile folder names are different.
    # eg: default profile in UI might be "Abc", but its profile name is Default
    # eg: another profile in UI might be "Test Account", but its profile name might be "Profile 1"
    # so identify the profile names properly at ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome

    cd ~/work/azureAdmin # just changed to this folder as I want to run admin login command from this folder so that some directory specific environment variables will be initialized in the background
    sleep 2 # giving 2 seconds wait in case background environment variables needs to be updated
    open -n -a "Google Chrome.app" --args --profile-directory="Profile 2" # this is the profile where I always login to chrome with admin account.
    sleep 5 # waiting for the browser to be initialized  - increase the timer if you have lot of tabs open in the profile instance
    az login # finally this will open the login browser tab in the desired profile.
}
```